# What is the equivalent to println / printf in Structure Synth's Eisenscript / javascript interpreter?

Tags: javascript, logging, context-free-grammar

[Structure Synth](http://structuresynth.sourceforge.net/) is a tool for generating 3D art from a grammar called Eisenscript. From their documentation, it looks like there should be [logging included in the capabilities of Structure Synth](http://structuresynth.sourceforge.net/development.php#primarycontent).

I have an Eisenscript file that uses javascript to render the output of context free grammars to files. I would like to print a log statement to the console or to a log file after each file is rendered so I could know which .es file is causing Structure Synth to crash. I suppose I could deduce which file is causing Structure Synth to crash just by looking at the files being generated, but it would be really nice to print to the console or a log file.

Does anyone know how custom logging or printing to standard output can be added to a [regular Eisenscript](http://structuresynth.sourceforge.net/reference.php) file (parsed as Eisenscript), or even to [a javascript snippet](http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2010/11/scripting-in-structure-synth/#more-775) invoked using Structure Synth's internal javascript interpreter? I tried `console.log("hi");` but the variable `console` cannot be found. I also tried `document.write("hi");` but `document` cannot be found.